# 'Action not found' from production version of Play App

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to dockerize Play 2.8 Scala App. I followed instructions from documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Deploying) and generated target (sbt clean & sbt dist). When I run the application from extracted zip with command:

```
sudo ./commentapi -Dplay.http.secret.key=ad31779d4ee49d5ad5162bf1429c32e2e9933f3b
```

it's starting fine, but when I try to communicate with my REST API using Postman, I'm getting following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    

    <title>Not Found</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body,
        pre {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;
            background: #ECECEC;
        }

        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            background: #AD632A;
            padding: 20px 45px;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
            border-bottom: 1px solid #9F5805;
            font-size: 28px;
        }

        p#detail {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 15px 45px;
            background: #F6A960;
            border-top: 4px solid #D29052;
            color: #733512;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
            font-size: 14px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #BA7F5B;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    
    <h1>Not Found</h1>

    <p id="detail">
        For request 'POST /comments'
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

When I open routes.config file, the routes are there. Also when I run my app directly from IntelliJ, everything works fine. I thought if it can be an issue with database connectivity, because I'm using Slick and for some reason my app doesn't crash if database is not running. But it would be strange, because in that case i should get an exception or some info about database not running.

If you know easier ways to dockerize play app, I would be also grateful for any advice on that topic.

**build.sbt:**

```
name := """commentapi"""

organization := "maciej"

version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.2"

artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  artifact.name + "." + artifact.extension
}

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.14"

routesImport += "constants.SortingOrder.Order"

dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9000, 9443)

// Adds additional packages into Twirl
//TwirlKeys.templateImports += "maciej.controllers._"

// Adds additional packages into conf/routes
// play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routesImport += "maciej.binders._"
```

**routes.config:**

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

POST    /comments                                   controllers.CommentController.createComment()
PUT     /comments/:id                               controllers.CommentController.updateComment(id: Long)
DELETE  /comments/:id                               controllers.CommentController.deleteComment(id: Long)
GET     /comments                                   controllers.CommentController.getAllComments(order: Option[Order], filter: Option[String], prefix: Option[String])
```

**application.conf:**

```
play.http.secret.key="QCY?tAnfk?aZ?iwrNwnxIlR6CTf:G3gf:90Latabg@5241AB`R5W:1uDFN];Ik@n"
play.server.pidfile.path=/dev/null

db {
  driver: "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
  db {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/commentapp"
    user = maciej
    password = admin
    driver = org.postgresql.Driver
    maxThreads = 5
  }
}

hosts {
    allowed = "localhost:9000"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the server-side logs, too? In production mode, Play doesn't return exception information to the client (for security reasons) so there is probably more detail in the server logs.

Comment: @TimMoore
I'm running it locally and there are no logs. There are only some standard logs directly in terminal when I start the app:

`2020-07-04 12:26:05 INFO  play.api.Play  Application started (Prod) (no global state)  
2020-07-04 12:26:05 INFO  play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer  Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000`

Comment: @Maciej_97 - can you put allowed to  allowed = ["."] and try again?

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue with Play Framework 2.8 (Java).
The issue was with .Dockerfile. I forgot to copy the play's "/public" folder to the container.
And project was successfully built without assets. (I am still wondering why project is successfully build. It should fail in such cases).
After adding the copy command "COPY ./public /root/app/public" (please take into account that you could have different destination folder) to .Dockerfile everything started working.

[Docker file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iL7j.png)